# Defining HTML Elements in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to figure out what is the best way to define HTML elements in typescript. I keep running into the following issue.

If i grab an array of dom nodes with `document.querySelectorAll` then the type will be `Element`. But if I set the type to `Element` and I want to set the style attribute then I get the following error

`Property 'style' does not exist on type 'Element'.`

But if I set the type to `HTMLElement` then I get the following error

`Argument of type 'Element' is not assignable to parameter of type 'HTMLElement'. Type 'Element' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLElement': accessKey, accessKeyLabel, autocapitalize, dir, and 111 more.`

Here is a very simple example code:

```
type El = HTMLElement

const boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.box')

const setStyle = (el: El) => {
  el.style.background = 'green'
}

boxes.forEach(box => {
  setStyle(box)
})
```

So what is the correct way to go about handling this? I could just do something like:

```
boxes.forEach(box => {
  setStyle(box as HTMLElement)
})
```

but it seems counter productive to constantly do this.

Comment: `const boxes: NodeListOf<HTMLElement> = document.querySelectorAll('.box');` I do not recommend type casting as Ashok has answered.

Answer (score 1):

The [`typed-query-selector` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typed-query-selector) can infer the correct type in quite a few cases. Though the query `'.box'` won't contain enough information, using `'div.box'` for example will make the code below type check without assertions:

```
import 'typed-query-selector'

type El = HTMLElement

const boxes = document.querySelectorAll('div.box')
// type: NodeListOf<HTMLDivElement>

const setStyle = (el: El) => {
  el.style.background = 'green'
}

boxes.forEach(box => {
  setStyle(box)
})
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAchgTzAUwCYFoCOBXNKZLAZzQBs0BjGaBAKHpXTgFFy4BeOACQBUAsgBl2aEGgB2MRlQgSS8AEYQAHmhJc4GCFTzipAOnyFkAZQrVaUAILlyACgQZgANwPKVCAJT0A9L7hAuAA9AH4ZOQU4MhhTFEpNewoALjZyLy4APjgAb3pAigMFZEp3AEMqAGsAcygIPAkMTQRatEkGAF9GD3UDADNoVgqAC3sPLNz86LRY+LQx1R8OnyA)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to cast the boxes as follow:

```js
const boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.box') as NodeListOf<HTMLElement>
```

This way the elements of `boxes` would be considered as `HTMLElement`, fixing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Ashok's answer.
Write a function that will return your elements.
e.g.

```js
const getElements = (selector: string) => {
    return document.querySelectorAll(selector) as NodeListOf<HTMLElement>; 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try its

```
let boxes =(<HTMLElement>document.querySelectorAll('.box'));
```

Comment: Due to react tsx being unfriendly to angle-bracket type assertions, they are discouraged. Better to use the `as` keyword. Also, there's no way that a `NodeListOf` should be asserted to `HTMLElement`.

Comment: let  boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.box') as NodeListOf<HTMLElement>